# Application hangs on GetRequestStream() after first request

Tags: c#, network-programming, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I've googled and searched here. Some suggest that streams were not being close, others suggested that it's a connection limit with ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit being set to 1. However, none of these seem to work.

My problem is, when i use this for the first time, it works:

```
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
     var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post.ToString());
     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

When I use it a second time, it freezes. Yes, I'm disposing my stream, yes im Aborting and closing my response and requests.

Here is my entire code segment:

```
public string get_hash(string strUsername, string strPassword, string strUniverse)
        {
            // Request VAR
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/");
            // Response VAR
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            // Cookie Var
            var cookie = new CookieContainer();

            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;            
            request.Timeout = 10;

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/main/login");

            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en,q=0.8");
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Host = "website.com";
            request.Headers.Add("Origin", "http://website.com");
            request.Referer = "http://website.com/";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36";
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie.GetCookies(request.RequestUri));

            // SET POST DATA HERE
            var post = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            post.Add("uni", strUni);
            post.Add("login", strUsername);
            post.Add("pass", strPassword);

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post.ToString());
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
            }

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            string strSSID = "Failed";

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var data = string.Empty;
                using (var sReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    data = sReader.ReadToEnd();
                    sReader.Close();
                    sReader.Dispose();
                }

                string strSSIDurl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();

                int intSSIDurlStart = strSSIDurl.IndexOf("PHPSESSID=") + 10;
                strSSID = strSSIDurl.Substring(intSSIDurlStart);
            }

            request.Abort();
            response.Close();
            response.Dispose();

            return strSSID;
        }
```

Comment: I would really recommend using Fiddler or some other web debug tool to see what's *really* happening at `GetRequestStream()`.  It's very hard to tell what might be the issue without seeing what is actually being sent / received.

Comment: Should it matter what is being sent or received? It should be .closed and .disposed but it seems to just hang until about a minute later when it finally times out.

Comment: Well it can't hurt to see if something at the endpoint is holding on or hanging your application.  When you debug through and step past the line in question, does it hang before going to the next line?  Also you don't need to call `Dispose()` and `Close()` *inside* the `using` block, that is what the `using` block does when it goes out of scope.

Comment: I'm aware of this and wanted to show beyond a doubt that the connection was told to close and be disposed. It starts to hang the instant it hits the using block on .GetRequestStream(). I don't think it's a problem with the endpoint.

Comment: Well obviously it's timing out at the endpoint, your code itself works and everything is being closed/disposed of properly, but for whatever reason the request is taking to long to get a response stream.  Not sure what else I can say beyond watch the actual request in Fiddler or some other web debugger.  If you don't already have this tool, I would really suggest you get it, its free and really helps see what's going on.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: "It starts to hang the instant it hits the using block on .GetRequestStream" pause the debugger and look at the call stack which will reach far into BCL code. The function names might be illuminating. Turn on "Show External Code".; You are not disposing the request and response in case of exceptions. I don't think this is material here. Do it anyway and retest.

Comment: @EvanL he actually doesn't dispose after the first .GetResponse(), I believe that is where his problem is

Answer (score 1):

you are not disposing the response from the first request.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // Not disposed
```

We had similar problem and disposing the response properly helped us.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question. But I spent one hour on this, and found that the answer is the corporation proxy, so adding the following to the web.config solved the issue, just in case someone from business had the same setup as mine and scatched all their hairs off...

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true"/>
    <settings>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```