# Silverlight freezes IE on GetRequestStreamAsync

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have the following Silverlight code. It uploads a file (`postData`) to a backend through the given url (`url`).

```
public async Task<HttpFileUploadResponse> PostFile(string url, byte[] postData, string fileName, bool isPDF) {
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";

    using (Stream writeStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()) {
        await writeStream.WriteAsync(postData, 0, postData.Length);
    }
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
        return ParseServerResponse(await readStream.ReadToEndAsync());
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is that is freezing Internet Explorer when the line `await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()` is reached.
Although similar questions have been resolved, such as:

- [Application hangs on GetRequestStream() after first request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337587/application-hangs-on-getrequeststream-after-first-request)
- [Why does HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() hang when trying to update an OData service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736056/why-does-httpwebrequest-getresponse-hang-when-trying-to-update-an-odata-servic)

I've followed the suggested steps, like setting the ContentLength, but the result is the same.

Also I've tried to change the URL to another one corresponding to another backend that is currently working with other Silverlight components that we have. These components also have an `await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()` but they are working perfectly.

I've tried to change the contentType. My workmates have used Fiddler to see the request but apparently nothing is being sent (I suppose it's because it freezes).

Any idea about what's happening here?

**EDIT:**

I have decompiled the AsynCompatLibExtensions.cs and TaskExtensions.cs to copy the GetRequestStreamAsync code in order to have a custom cloned class with logs among the instructions.

I have recompiled the solution using this class and the strange thing is that I'm not seeing any log. So I suppose it's freezing when it enters GetRequestStreamAsync but before it reaches any code line inside.

Any idea?